# Juego de Mancala en C++

Tags: c++

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito ayuda para poder resolver los incisos de movimiento del juego de Mancala
este esta representado por el arreglo de 2x6 donde los elementos todos son 4, los movimientos estan dados por la cadena `C` y estos movimientos se hacen cuando se ingresa ya sea desde A a F o a hasta f.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void MovimientoOware(int T[][6],char x);
void SucesionOware(int T[][6], char *x);
void Imprimir(int T[][6]);

int main(){
int T[2][6];
char C[100];
cin.getline(C,99,'\n');

for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<6; j++){
        T[i][j]=4;
    }
}

SucesionOware(T,C);
Imprimir(T);

return 0;
}

void Imprimir(int T[][6]){
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
       for(int j=0; j<6; j++){
          cout<<T[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    }
}

 void MovimientoOware(int T[][6],char C){
     switch(C){
case 'f':
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<6; ){
            T[0][0]--;
            T[1][0]++;
            T[1][1]++;
            T[1][2]++;
            T[1][3]++;
        }
    }
    break;

case 'e':
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<6; ){
            T[0][1]--;
            T[0][0]++;
            T[1][0]++;
            T[1][1]++;
            T[1][2]++;
        }
    }
    break;

case 'd':
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<6; ){
            T[0][2]--;
            T[0][1]++;
            T[0][0]++;
            T[1][0]++;
            T[1][1]++;
        }
    }
    break;

case 'c':
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<6; ){
            T[0][3]--;
            T[0][2]++;
            T[0][1]++;
            T[0][0]++;
            T[1][0]++;
        }
    }

case 'b':
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<6; ){
            T[0][4]--;
            T[0][3]++;
            T[0][2]++;
            T[0][1]++;
            T[0][0]++;
        }
    }
    break;

case 'a':
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<6; ){
            T[0][5]--;
            T[0][4]++;
            T[0][3]++;
            T[0][2]++;
            T[0][1]++;
        }
    }
    break;

case 'A':
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<6; ){
            T[1][0]--;
            T[0][0]++;
            T[0][1]++;
            T[0][2]++;
            T[0][3]++;
        }
    }
    break;

case 'B':
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<6; ){
            T[1][1]--;
            T[1][0]++;
            T[0][0]++;
            T[0][1]++;
            T[0][2]++;
        }
    }
    break;

case 'C':
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<6; ){
            T[1][2]--;
            T[1][1]++;
            T[1][0]++;
            T[0][0]++;
            T[0][1]++;
        }
    }
    break;

case 'D':
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<6; ){
            T[1][3]--;
            T[1][2]++;
            T[1][1]++;
            T[1][0]++;
            T[0][0]++;
        }
    }

case 'E':
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<6; ){
            T[1][4]--;
            T[1][3]++;
            T[1][2]++;
            T[1][1]++;
            T[1][0]++;
        }
    }
    break;

case 'F':
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<6; ){
            T[1][5]--;
            T[1][4]++;
            T[1][3]++;
            T[1][2]++;
            T[1][1]++;
        }
    }
    break;

    break;
}
 }
```

Comment: y cual es la duda?

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: He intentado primero captar los datos que ingresa el usuario para asi poder hacer los movimientos del juego, intente crear un switch donde se evalua lo que se ingreso a traves de la cadena c y asi cambiar los valores que contiene el arreglo T pero no he alcanzando buenos resultados con lo que he intentado

Comment: Y donde esta el switch? No vamos a hacer el ejercicio por vos, pero si vamos a ayudrate a corregir tus errores y tu logica...

Comment: Ya aplique el cambio del switch que te mencione, y en mi mente lo que tengo es que el FOR decrementa los elementos que se encuentran en su posicion y los va repartiendo uno por uno  en los demas elementos del arreglo

Comment: Leiste tu codigo? Haces un for, pero la idea de iterar sobre algo es que el codigo que vaya adentro tenga algo que ver con el for.. sin embargo, vos siempre moves los mismos elementos de la matriz... muchas veces

Comment: Es que asi el juego digamos todos los elementos del arreglo empiezan en 4 asi que los movimientos que hace es tomar los valores de esa posicion y repartir uno a uno en los elementos restantes del arreglo todo esto en contra del sentido del reloj

Comment: Entonces no entiendo ni tu codigo ni el juego. Tus for no tienen una logica, porque recorres la matriz pero dentro de los for no usas la posicion que estas recorriendo si no que siempre sumas o restas de la misma posicion. Esperemos que alguien pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Lo lograste terminar...??? si es asi podrias mostrarme como quedo..??

Answer (score 2):

En el juego de Mancala, se cogen las fichas que haya en el agujero elegido y se va echando una ficha en los siguientes hoyos... es decir, para empezar tus movimientos preprogramados están mal:

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<6; ){
        T[0][0]--;
        T[1][0]++;
        T[1][1]++;
        T[1][2]++;
        T[1][3]++;
    }
}
```

Primero porque solo quitas una ficha del hoyo en cuestión ¿Qué pasa si el hoyo ya está vacío? ¿Se admiten hoyos con una cantidad de fichas negativas?

Y segundo porque tras quitar una ficha... añades 4 al juego!!!. Es decir, el juego incorpora tres fichas nuevas cada ronda!!!

Como he dicho, el número de iteraciones debe depender del número de fichas que haya en el agujero seleccionado:

```
int fichas = T[0][0];
T[0][0] = 0;

int a = 0, b = 0;
while( fichas-- )
{
  if( a == 0 )
  {
    if( b == 0 )
      a = 1;
    else
      b--;
  }
  else
  {
    if( b == 3 )
      a = 0;
    else
      b++;
  }

  T[a][b]++;
}
```

Aquí no estoy teniendo en cuenta los hoyos de los jugadores (donde van sumando puntos). Ignoro si tienes que tenerlos en cuenta y en tu código no los mencionas en ningún momento.